# Implement a Folder Browser

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to use a `FolderBrowser` in my WPF application to select a folder containing images. I do know about the `System.Windows.Forms` version, but it makes `MessageBox` ambiguous, which makes it difficult to show other messages to my user. Is there a different way to do this or should I use a custom control. Or Is there a way to get past the ambiguous error?

Comment: What ambiguous error?

Comment: http://tyburnfolderbrowsers.codeplex.com/

Comment: Or the `CommonOpenFileDialog` from the [Windows 7 API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). Just set the `IsFolderPicker` property true. Looks a lot better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just import forms as:

```
using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;
```

Then when you want to create a Folder dialog you can write:

```
Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
```

That should get rid of the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The MessageBox of WinForms is in a different namespace. So if you have a `using` for both namespaces (`System.Windows.Forms` for Forms and `Systems.Windows` for WPF) at the beginning of your source code file, you have to provide the full namespace when accessing classes with identical name in both namespaces.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[...]
public void MyFunction()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ambiguous errors happen because 2 or more things have the same name and signature, you simply need to be more specific when calling MessageBox to get around it.

```
blah.blah.MessageBox("message");
```

instead of

```
MessageBox("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont put `System.Windows.Forms` in `using`, so you avoid ambiguous `MessageBox`.

```
public bool SelectDirectory(out String directoryName)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    directoryName = String.Empty;
    dlg.SelectedPath = String.Empty;
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        directoryName = dlg.SelectedPath;
        return true;
   }
   else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just include this method and continue with WPF elsewhere.